# How do I return a Random number every time in Math Random.?

Tags: arrays, random, swap, alexa-skills-kit

I just have a question,

I have been building alexa skill. (the Concept is Randomize Positivity)
but somehow it keep returning the same sentence.... 
this is my code...

```
` for (var j = 0; j < index; j++){
        var rand =  Math.floor(Math.random() * index);
        index -= 1;

        var temp = indexList[index];
        indexList[index] = indexList[rand];
        indexList[rand] = temp;

    }`// I also swap the words so It would sure not to return the same but somehow  it happens..
```

and the index  is about 15 strings for now...
my Question is  how do I make it random as possible?

Comment: Can you tag with the language this is?

Comment: Do you seed the random generator with something like the time?

Comment: Sounds to me like you don't actually want it random, you want it to return different sentences each time. Many ways to do this: one is to shuffle a list and return one from the list each time until they're all used, then reshuffle. Another might be to randomize each choice, but give more weight to each choice based on how recently it was shown.

Answer (score 0):

You're just trying to shuffle an array, right? See the [Fisher-Yates shuffle.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm) You're already almost doing the same thing.

I tried this and it worked fine.

```
var indexList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15];
var rand;
var temp;

for (let i = 0; i < indexList.length; i++) {
  rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
  temp = indexList[i];
  indexList[i] = indexList[rand];
  indexList[rand] = temp;
  console.log(indexList);
}
```

It printed the following, showing that it is shuffling the array more and more each step:

```
> Array [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
> Array [2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
> Array [3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
> Array [4, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
> Array [4, 1, 5, 3, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
> Array [4, 6, 5, 3, 2, 1, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
> Array [4, 6, 5, 3, 2, 1, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
> Array [4, 6, 5, 3, 2, 8, 7, 1, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
> Array [4, 6, 5, 3, 2, 8, 9, 1, 7, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
> Array [4, 6, 5, 3, 2, 8, 9, 1, 10, 7, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
> Array [4, 6, 5, 3, 2, 8, 9, 1, 10, 7, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
> Array [4, 6, 5, 3, 2, 8, 9, 1, 12, 7, 11, 10, 13, 14, 15]
> Array [4, 6, 5, 3, 2, 8, 9, 1, 12, 7, 11, 10, 13, 14, 15]
> Array [4, 6, 14, 3, 2, 8, 9, 1, 12, 7, 11, 10, 13, 5, 15]
> Array [4, 6, 15, 3, 2, 8, 9, 1, 12, 7, 11, 10, 13, 5, 14]
```

Comment: that so cool  man, I'll try that also the randomize  picker for the array  is randomize to, 
`var indexList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15];
var rand;
var temp;
var randomizePicker;

for (let i = 0; i < indexList.length; i++) {
  rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
  temp = indexList[i];
  indexList[i] = indexList[rand];
  indexList[rand] = temp;
  console.log(indexList);
 randomizePicker =Math.floor(Math.random() * indexList.length);
 var answer = indexList[randomizePicker]
 console.log(answer);
}`

Comment: so I did some changes and it still return, some same value,maybe this is how the code should be?